# Proper way to pass/read CSV derived JSON with Flask/Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, csv, flask

So what I'm trying to do eventually is read a CSV on the backend using Python/Flask and display it as an HTML table using Javascript.

I've stripped things down to just trying to get console.log() to display the JSON values getting passed from my Python routine. Once I can retrieve my JSON values at will, building the table should be no issue.

Here's my code right now:

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import json
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)
filePath = "/protec/test.csv"

@app.route("/") 
def index(): 
    tableData = get_table_data()
    return render_template("index.html", tableData=tableData)

def get_table_data():
    tableData = []
    with open(filePath, encoding='utf-8') as file:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(file)

        for row in csvReader:
            tableData.append(row)

    with open(filePath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        tableString = json.dumps(tableData, indent=4)

    return tableString

if __name__ == "__main__": app.run()
```

**script portion of index.html that (for now) triggers via onpageshow**

```
<script>
    function build_table() {
        var parsedData = ' {{ tableData }} ';
        console.log(parsedData);
    }
</script>
```

**my very simple test.csv file**

```
first,last,age,hair
john,doe,29,brown
jane,doent,30,blond
```

From Python, I've tried returning both tableData and tableString.
When I return tableString, I get an error when I inspect in the browser.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

When I return tableData, I get... something... in the console, but it's not really JSON and has some weird values that (I think) represent quotes.

```
[{&#39;first&#39;: &#39;john&#39;, &#39;last&#39;: &#39;doe&#39;, &#39;age&#39;: &#39;29&#39;, &#39;hair&#39;: &#39;brown&#39;}, {&#39;first&#39;: &#39;jane&#39;, &#39;last&#39;: &#39;doent&#39;, &#39;age&#39;: &#39;30&#39;, &#39;hair&#39;: &#39;blond&#39;}]
```

I'm new to web development and frameworks and couldn't seem to find an example that was passing more than a single JSON record at a time. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal you just need to pass your list `tableData` to the template.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import json
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)
filePath = '/protec/test.csv'

@app.route("/")
def index():
    tableData = get_table_data()
    return render_template('index.html', tableData=tableData)

def get_table_data():
    tableData = []
    with open(filePath, encoding='utf-8') as file:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(file)
        tableData = [row for row in csvReader]
    return tableData
```

Within the template you can then use the jinja2 filter [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson) to convert the data into a JSON-compliant format. Now you get an array of objects which you can process with JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
        (function build_table() {
            var data = {{ tableData | tojson }};
            console.log(data);
        })();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```